# Fast manipulation of Dates in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have around 34000 vectors of dates that I have to change the day and move the month. I have tried this with a loop and using the `mapply` function but it is extremely slow.
This is an example of what I have:

```
library(lubridate)
list_dates = replicate(34000,seq(as.Date("2019-03-14"),length.out = 208,by = "months"),simplify = F)
new_day = round(runif(34000,1,30))
new_day[sample(1:34000,10000)] = NA

new_dates = mapply(FUN = function(dates,day_change){
  day(dates) = ifelse(is.na(rep(day_change,length(dates))),day(dates),rep(day_change,length(dates)))
  dates = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(rep(day_change,length(dates))),dates,dates%m-%months(1)),origin = "1970-01-01")
  return(dates)
},dates = list_dates,day_change = as.list(new_day),SIMPLIFY = F)
```

The variable `new_dates` should contain a list of the original dates move accordingly to the variable `new_day`. The function in side works like this:

1. if `new_day` is different from NA it will change the day of the dates to the new one
2. if  `new_day` is different from NA it will move the months of the dates one behind.

I'm open to any solution that will increase the speed regardless of the packages use (if they are in CRAN).

**EDIT**

So based on the comments I reduce the example for a list of 2 vector of dates each containing 2 dates and created a manual vector of new days:

```
list_dates = replicate(2,seq(as.Date("2019-03-14"),length.out = 2,by = "months"),simplify = F)

new_day = c(9,NA)
```

This is the original input (variable list_dates):

```
[[1]]
[1] "2019-03-14" "2019-04-14"

[[2]]
[1] "2019-03-14" "2019-04-14"
```

and the expected output of the `mapply` function is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "2019-02-09" "2019-03-09"

[[2]]
[1] "2019-03-14" "2019-04-14"
```

As you can see the first vector of dates was change to the day 9 and each date was lag one month. The second vector of dates did not change because `new_dates` is `NA` for that value.

Comment: Can you reduce the input to say 10 dates and show what you are trying to do along with your expected output ?

Comment: Additionally to Ronak's comment please use a fixed random seed to ensure reproducibility of sample data and expected output. I'm also not sure what you mean by *"it will move the months of the dates one behind."* Do you mean to say that `new_month = old_month - 1` for all dates of the `list_dates` element?

Comment: There is some ambiguity as to wether you want to use the function `day` from `lubridate` or index the arguement `day` that you are passing to the `mapply`. If it is the latter, then you should be using square breackets `[]` . In any case, avoid naming your variable the same as functions that you intend to use

Comment: I updated the question to be minimal as possible. @Rohit thanks for the comment about the day argument that was a mistake I had from the original function, already change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `lubridate` solution

```
library(lubridate)
mapply(
    function(x, y) { if (!is.na(y)) {
            day(x) <- y;
            month(x) <- month(x) - 1
        }
        return(x) },
    list_dates, new_day, SIMPLIFY = F)
#[[1]]
#[1] "2019-02-09" "2019-03-09"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "2019-03-14" "2019-04-14"
```

Or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
map2(list_dates, new_day, function(x, y) {
    if (!is.na(y)) {
        day(x) <- y
        month(x) <- month(x) - 1
    }
    x })
```

Comment: Thanks but I compare your function and mine with 2 dates with a length of 208 in `microbenchmark` and mi original function is marginally faster.

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade I see; I've added a `purrr` option, not sure how that compares in a `microbenchmark` comparison. PS: The downvote is not really warranted here and quite frankly is a somewhat misguided response to the general concept of SO respondents giving free advice; the solution reproduces your expected output.

Comment: The new function its faster. Regarding the downvote your original answer was basically my same function but instead of an ifelse you used an if and it was slower which was not the intended result of the question (I already had a function that did it and faster). I know its free advice and thanks for it but i also got downvoted for a legitimate question. The result remains pretty slow but i guess you didn't try it with more than a 100 dates.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Maurits' solution, if you want to further increase the speed of computation, you may want to consider using multiple cores with `doParallel`

```
library(data.table)
library(doParallel)

registerDoParallel(3)
df <- data.table(new_day,list_dates)

mlply(df,
      function(new_day,list_dates){

        list_dates <- list_dates[[1]]

        if(!is.na(new_day)){
          day(list_dates) <- new_day
          list_dates <-  list_dates %m-% months(1)
        }

        return(list_dates)
      }, .parallel = T, .paropts = list(.packages='lubridate')
)
```

Comment: Its not possible for me to paralellize this function because i'm already in running a bigger function that calls this one in with `foreach`